# Upload failes with files larger than 1 GB

Tags: php, jquery, file, upload, blueimp

we have implemented the great blueim jquery file upload plugin.

After increased the settings in php.ini to allow uploads with larger files we get it to work with files with 1 GB. We do not have any errors in the php error log anymore.

But we are not able to upload files larger than 1 GB in size.

We have got a `Windows server 2012 R2`, with `IIS` and `PHP 5.6`.

We already edited the request filtering settings to the largest possible values:

```
Maxmimum allowed content length  (4294967295)
Maximum URL length = (4294967295)
Maximum query string = (4294967295)
```

We also have disabled the anti virus applikation on the server.

We then enabled the request filtering settings in `IIS`. But this did not help us.

We can follow the upload of the test file with 2 GB in size in the `C:\Windows\Temp` directory. It grows to the 2 GB size. The plugin on the website tells us 100 % but then we get internal server error.

What else could we change / check to get this to work ?

Thank you very much for your support.

Kind regards
Winer5

Comment: *we get internal server error.* what is the error-message? take a look in the log file

Comment: sorry for the delay. The IIS Log file shows an error 500.0 and then some more numbers.